# erro 500 na instanciação do servlet

Tags: servlet

Olá.

Estou tentando fazer uma servlet, mas o tomcat não encontra essa classe do servlet. O erro é:

> HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class servidor.PrimeiraQuestao--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

servidor é o pacote e PrimeiraQuestao é a classe.

Segue o erro do código do web-app.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>teds</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>questaoum</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servidor.PrimeiraQuestao</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>questaoum</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/questaoum</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Coloque a estrutura das pastas, é provavel que você tenha colocado no nome da classe faltando algo ou você colocou a classe na pasta errada.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento o tipo de projeto é dinamic web project. Na estrutura não alterei nada, a não ser cirar o pacote servidor e a pasta jsp dentro da pasta web-content.

Comment: Era isso que eu precisa saber, em que pasta criou, edita a pergunta e posta a estrutura, pode ser até um print (um dos poucos casos que print ajuda rsrs), isso já ajuda.